# is it possible to install JDK 7 Or 8 on mac os x without official oracle dmg file?

Tags: java, linux, macos

I want to install JDK 7 by using a .tar file that is related to my Linux installation. I think there should be a way to install JDK independent of OS. Can some one give me some tips about that? Is it possible to install JDK independent of my operating system?

Comment: Linux binaries will not work on OSX.

Comment: I know that os specific file dont work on another os but I think should be a raw an independent  os version of JDK that should be possible to customize for special purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the Linux binaries on Mac OS X but you can absolutely install JDK 7 or 8 without an official Oracle dmg file.

You could build [from source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8) or get a version [built from source](http://openjdk-osx-build.en.softonic.com/mac). The "raw independent os version of JDK" is generally known as the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually extract the installer with an extraction program. The source is contained within.

For example, I am on Windows. I extract the installer and get `tools.zip`. I then extract this and I get a bunch of folders for a full portable JDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually require the development tools and your main objection is to the .dmg files then it's also worth noting that .tar.gz archives are available for the JRE.  With these it would be possible to select the OS specific binary at runtime and unpack using the same procedure.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html